# Background Image in an Image Map

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am trying to make a user generated nav bar.

This nav bar because it is dynamically created may have more tabs on it than the width of the nav bar.

That being the case, I would like to make it so that the nav will scroll from left to right.

Currently I use an image mapping technique where I plot coordinates on an image and move divs based on position which calculates speed and direction of movement.

The problem is background images may not have image maps applied to them. The general workaround is to create invisible divs on top that would represent my coordinates, but since my text would be there, and I don't want to mess with a z-index at all, that option is deprecated.

Any ideas how to do this any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.

http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/